# How can i send a model in POST REST call from Chrome developer tools?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, rest

i am making a REST(POST method) call from Chrome -> Developer tools. When i am using following request, when it hits my controller, params: name, id are getting sent as null/empty, 0.
 If i remove '{person {}}', then the values get passed correctly. i would like to structure the request properly, how can i pass request with person like-

```
 {
   person{
      name: "abc",
      id:26684378
 }
```

Chrome request:

```
fetch('http://someurl.com/Save', {
       method: 'POST',
       body: JSON.stringify(
       {
          person
          {
            name: "abc",
            id:26684378
          }

       }),
       headers: {
       'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
     }
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(console.log)
```

Model

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class Person
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public string Save(Person person)  // person object here has empty/null property value
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your `JSON.stringify` call is missing `:` after `person`.

```
JSON.stringify(
   {
      person:
      {
        name: "abc",
        id:26684378
      }
   })
```

will result in next json:

```
{"person":{"name":"abc","id":26684378}}
```

If this is desired input, then you need to add model containing `Person`:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class PersonInput
{    
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

And change your action in controller to accept it:

```
public string Save(PersonInput personInput)  
{
}
```

Comment: @prys was glad to help!